# Issue with nesting helpers in meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, handlebars.js

In my meteor.js app I have the following template:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="userTabs">
        {{#if tabIs "editedTab"}}
            <li class="active">
                <a class='tabButton' id="editedTab">Edited</a>
            </li>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if tabIs "starredTab"}}
            <li class="active">
                <a class='tabButton' id="starredTab">Starred</a>
            </li>
        {{/if}}
    </ul>
    <div id="usernav" class="tab-content">   
        {{#if tabIs "editedTab"}}
            <div id="edited" class="tab-pane active">
                <ul>
                    {{#each edited}}
                        <li><a class="left-nav" href="{{entryLink this}}">{{title}}</a></li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div> 
        {{/if}}
        {{#if tabIs "starredTab"}}
        <div id="starred" class="tab-pane active" >
            <ul>
                {{#each starred}}
                <li><a class="left-nav" href="{{entryLink this}}">{{title}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
```

Which has the helper tabIs nested within the #if (according to the meteor docs this is acceptable because of an extension they added to handlebars.)

I then have in coffeescript:

```
Template.leftNav.tabIs = ->
    Session.get('tabIs')

Template.leftNav.events =
    'click .tabButton' : (evt) ->
         $el = $(evt.target)
         Session.set( 'tabIs' , $el.attr('id'))
```

and seed the session variable in Meteor.startup:

```
Meteor.startup ->
    Session.set('tabIs', 'editedTab')
```

The problem is both tabs render at all times and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a condition to the helper statement too! At the moment it returns 'editedTab' which is not `null` so it returns true. (The condition is `if(Session('editedTab')) {..}`)

Alter your helper to:

```
Template.leftNav.tabIs = (path) ->
  Session.get("tabIs") is path
```

(Using equals can be more efficient for checking equality than the above:)

```
Template.leftNav.tabIs = (path) ->
  Session.equals "tabIs", path
```